# Get img src from a cell Javascript

Tags: javascript, row, cell

I want to take the `src` of an image of out every cell from a table's `tr`.

Here's what I am trying to  do:

```
    function returnPics(){
    var x = document.getElementById("table2").rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i=0 ; i <x ; i++){
        console.log("in");
        var link = document.getElementById("table2").rows[0].cells[i].childNodes[i].src ;
        console.log(link);
    }
}
```

I have also tried the `getAttribute` method:

```
var link = document.getElementById("table2").rows[0].cells[i].getAttribute("src")
```

Comment: Please post your HTML or provide jsfiddle example

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery it is really simple.

```
$('#table2 img').each(function() {
  var link=$(this).attr('src');
  console.log(link);
}
```

Comment: This is javascript question. Not jquery

Comment: Aw, come on. You know jQuery is the right tool for this task. Why not advise the poster to do it the easy way?